# PostgreSQL Update does not updated properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm trying to update records to the values in column **Number** in a different table matching by ID, but it updates all rows in the Number column to the value which was matched by the very fist matched ID in the other table.

```
  UPDATE public.table
            SET number = s.number,
                updatedt =  now()                
            -- select a.* , s.number
            FROM public.Department AS a
            INNER JOIN public.Department_stg AS s
                ON a.id = s.id 
                 AND a.number <> s.number;
                --AND COALESCE (a.number, 1) = COALESCE (s.number, 1) ; 
                --AND COALESCE (CAST (a.number AS VARCHAR(20) ),'') <> COALESCE (CAST (s.numberAS VARCHAR(20) ),'') ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike T-SQL in postgreSQL JOIN is not needed to update. We can just pass the source values table in the From clause and keep the table to be updated in the UPDATE clause.

```
UPDATE public.table AS a
SET number= s.number,
    updatedt =  now() 
FROM public.Department_stg AS s
WHERE a.id = s.id
AND COALESCE (a.number, 1) <> COALESCE (s.number, 1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `WHERE` condition to join `"table"` with the inner join from the `FROM` clause; perhaps

```
WHERE "table".id = a.id
```

Without such a condition, `"table".number` will be updated to any of the rows from the inner join.